# What do I do with a cracked screen?

Tags: canon-550d, repair, diy, glass, rear-lcd

I just cracked the screen on my out-of-warranty Canon EOS T2i. It just *happened* to fall right onto a corner of the foot of a table.

The glass cover for the screen is smashed, but the LCD is still intact.

Since the camera is out of warranty and I'm feeling adventurous, can anyone recommend a place where I could order such a part? All the Googling I did yielded only screen protectors.

Possibly a side question, but are there any screen protectors that could prevent screen cracking? I could just go out and buy something that looks nice, but I think advice from actual users might be more valuable.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the replacement part directly from Canon for about $30-40 USD. It doesn't seem like an overly complicated replacement either, you just have to be a bit DIY to get the job done without throwing your camera across the room.

I found a tutorial on how to do it for a 5DMK II [here](http://blog.johnwurth.com/?p=16).

Once you do replace the cracked protector, I would recommend a [Giottos LCD screen protector](http://www.giottos.com/SP.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I looked online and the screen apparently is held in with just an adhesive strip lining the glass, so I doubt it'll be hard to replace. Is Canon the only manufacturer I could get the screen from?

Comment: I just got off the phone with Canon and they will be shipping me both a replacement glass window and the adhesive tape for $16.00 + $5.00? in shipping. Wow, I didn't think it would be so cheap... Thanks!

Comment: Better yet! The price I found was for the 5DMK II, so I would guess they charge a bit less for your model, which is nice. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be ordering a screen protector along with it ;) I should be more careful when I use Magic Lantern, as the camera fell off of a table while I was shooting a timelapse...